# calling constructor on a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to wrap my head around javascript prototypal inheritance and while reading through John Resig's book "Pro Javascript Techniques", I was trying things like this:

```
alert("me".constructor); //Correctly return String
alert(alert.constructor); //Correctly return Function
```

However,

```
alert(55.constructor);//I was expecting Number, but it returns error "SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal" in FF and in IE, it says it is expecting ")"
```

I also tried other functions that should work on a number, like `toFixed()` `toPrecision()` and even `toString()`  but nothing works!

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `()` around the number, like this:

```
alert((55).constructor);
```

---

**Taken from the comments:**

The parser is expecting a decimal number, but fails because it sees the letter "c" instead. Alternatively, `55..constructor` would also work (because `55.` is just `55.0` or `55`).

Comment: Yes, the parser is expecting a decimal number, but fails because it sees the letter `c` instead. Alternatively, `55..constructor` would also work (because `55.` is just `55.0` or `55`).

Comment: You can also do `55.0.constructor` :-P

Comment: Nice, didn't know about 55.. and 55.0.

Comment: Thanks guys! I thought the parser was as smart as Ruby's  `55.to_s`